# How to assign submatrices in elements of a list

Tags: r

For example:
Let M be some matrix mXn matrix where n is large enough to make manual entry impossible.

tmp_list[1] <- M[,1:10]

tmp_list[2] <- M[,11:20]

.
.
.

tmp_list[last] <- M[end - 9,end]

The problem I'm working on is sort of monte carlo, repeating an experiment involving a random mXn matrix 100K times. I'm still pretty new to R, I've done it using a for loop, but it obviously took a very long time.  So I'm hoping to assign each "experiment" to an element of a list and use lapply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's take the easy case, and you can expand it from there

say n=100, develop your start indeces

```
n<-100
byParam<-10
starts<-seq(1, n-(byParam-1), by=byParam)
```

then lapply

```
tmp_list<-lapply(starts, function(startIndex) M[, startIndex:(startIndex+(byParam-1)])
```

just one way to do it, becomes a bit more complicated if n is not a nice multiple of 10 (or whatever you set the "byParam" equal to).  If that is the case then you can develop your start and end indeces, and then use mapply instead

```
#given start and end indeces
tmp_list<-mapply(function(startInd, endInd){
     M[, startInd:endInd}, 
    startInd=starts, endInd=ends)
```

Now lapply and mapply are still iterative, so I wouldn't expect massive improvement on time efficiency

**EDIT**

After discussion in the comments, here is a solution for the entire set up, not just the above question

```
tmp_list<-lapply(1:1000, function(i){
     vect<-sample(c(0,1), 10*1000, replace=TRUE)
     dim(vect)<-c(10, 1000)
     vect
})
```

Let's break this down, it makes everything very simple.

We first create a random sample of 1's and 0's, of the length 10*1000 (the number of elements in each sub-matrix).  We can then neatly convert that vector to a matrix by assigning it's dim attribute to be c(10, 1000), which changes its form to have 10 rows and 1000 columns.  Then we return that into a list at the index i.  We lapply over 1:1000, or iterate 1000 times.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I could reference "M" inside the lapply function.  That makes total sense, thanks.

Comment: @Steve187 watch out for scoping here.  M can only be referenced if it exists within the current or parent environment of the lapply or mapply call

Comment: Do you have any advice for creating a very large matrix efficiently?     <br/> I'm doing: <br/> <pre> <big_mat <-matrix(sample(c(0,1),num_flipsnum_coinsnum_trials,replace = TRUE),nrow = num_flips,ncol = num_coins*num_trials) > Where, <br/> Where num_flips = 10; num_trials = 100000; num_coins = 1000. <br/> This step is taking a very long time, and the resulting matrix takes up a lot of space. Is there a better way to do this in R?

Comment: @Steve187 that code doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me (bigmat<-flipmat<- matrix.... ?  it never looks good in the comments anyway.)  All of the runtime there is in the sample call, not creating a matrix.  So you're basically just wanting a vector of random 0's and 1's of length 10*1000*100000 and convert that vector to a matrix?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm trying to figure out the markdown syntax but making a mess of it.  Yes, I'm creating a (10)X(100000*1000) matrix of {0,1}.  Then, per the original question, assigning each 10X1000 submatrix to an element of a list so I can use sapply and hopefully perform the calculation faster than using a loop.

Comment: @Steve187 you can actually do all that in one step.  I'll add an edit to the answer see what you think

Comment: not going to say it'll be a ton faster, there's no way to get around all the sampling you have to do, but you do get around having to do the matrix creation then the subsetting, which will save some time

Comment: That works exactly how I was hoping, and is considerably faster.  Thanks a lot, you've been very helpful.